# proof verification analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Exists an  analytic function $g(z)$ such that $g^{'}(z)= \frac{1}{z^{2}-1}$ in the annulus $1<|z|<2$.

My answer is yes i calculate the integral of $g$ which is $\frac{1}{2}(\log(z+1) + \log(z-1))$ and this function is analytic in this annulus.

Am I right?

Comment: Be careful with logarithms: you need a branch, and for that you must not be able to go around the origin in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate $g'(z)$. Is it equal to $\frac1{z^2-1}$? If so, then the answer is yes, you are correct.